# SQL Server merge replication across domains

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I'm getting the following message when trying to set up merge replication on SQL Server 2008 R2:

> *The Merge Agent failed to locate the partitioned snapshot for this
>   subscription in the expected location. If the publication does not
>   support Subscriber-requested snapshot generation, ensure that the
>   partitioned snapshot for this subscription has been generated.*

I've tried adding the following SQL to the run agent step of the snapshot agent

```
-Output C:\Temp\OUTPUTFILE.txt -Outputverboselevel 2
```

but that just seems to make the agent crash with the following message:

> *The replication agent has not logged a progress message in 10 minutes.
>   This might indicate an unresponsive agent or high system activity.
>   Verify that records are being replicated to the destination and that
>   connections to the Subscriber, Publisher, and Distributor are still
>   active.*

All ideas gratefully received.

Comment: Have you reviewed this article? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be to do with the permissions on the snapshot folder. I added a user to each server with the same credentials and ran the subscription under that account.

Still don't know why I couldn't get verbose logging to happen, but in the end I didn't need it.